# SASS variables not working

Tags: css, sass

I am new to SASS and I just simply follow the steps given on SASS guide website to install SASS but it is not working at all and does not convert my SASS into CSS, like i have taken a variable for colors but it did not work.I think I am missing some major part in this please anyone guide me so i can do my assignment further.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SASS1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass1.scss"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="sub_container">
                <div class="first_box">
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="second_box">
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                    <div class="inner_box"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

SASS:

```
$black_color : #000;
$voilet_color : #2A2E54;
.container
{
    width: 602px;
    height: 501px;
    border: 3px solid $black_color;
    background-color: $voilet_color;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sub_container
{
    width: 442px;
    height: 321px;
    border: 10px solid #C1F1FD;
    position: relative;
    top: 76px;
    left: 76px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, inset 0 0 1px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, inset 0 0 1px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000, inset 0 0 1px #000;
}
.first_box, .second_box
{
    width: 386px;
    height: 114px;
    border: 10px solid #FFF189;
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
.inner_box
{
    width: 30px;
    height: 56px;
    border: 10px solid #FFB286;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 19px;
    margin-top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to convert sass to css?

Comment: Is there any way? I thought it automatically converts

Comment: No, it will not get automatically converted to css. You can use the following command  in terminal: sass --watch style.scss:style.css

Comment: in place of style.scss i need to write my file name?

Comment: Yes, style.scss has to be replaced with your corresponding files names.

Comment: So in refernce link i need to link my css file or sass file

Comment: It's so confusing my files still not converting when i check it in page source

Comment: style.scss has to be replaced with the file name where you write your sass styles and style.css is the file where you wish to have all your converted css file.

Comment: Ya i got that but i'm asking that in my html file should i link my sass(style.scss) file or my css file(style.css)?

Comment: In html, you should link your css file.

Comment: So if i need to make changes in my style i will make changes in sass file it will automatically convert it into CSS?

Comment: Because now SASS is no more linked to my HTML so i think any changes in SASS would not affect my structure.

Comment: Yes, what happens here is whenever there is a change in scss file, it will automatically get detected and your css file will get updated correspondingly. You don't need to do anything in this css file.

Comment: Ohh got it. Thanks for helping

Comment: if you found this useful, up vote the answer provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the terminal, run the following command in the folder where the stylesheets are. It will detect whenever there is a change in `.scss` file and it will update `.css` file. This css file has to be referred in the html file.

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to compile the `.scss` files to `.css` with a `sass` compiler like http://koala-app.com/. Then, you can access just the `.css` files in your html.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sass1.css"/>
```